# How to read value from a file in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I am trying to get read value from a file in shell script based on input. How I can do it ?

I tried in different way but not able to read value in below file.

```
# dates
dates:
    start: '10-09-2018'
    end: '10-02-2019'

# filters
filters:
    - table: 'employee'
      column: 'sex'
      operation: '=='
      value: M
    - table: 'employee'
      column: 'department'
      operation: 'notin'
      value: ['operation', 'sales']
    - table: 'organisation'
      column: 'org_id'
      operation: '=='
      value: 124
- table: 'organisation'
      column: 'org_name'
      operation: '=='
      value: XYZ LIMITED
```

My expected output, 
If I pass '**filters**' and table name '**employee**' as input, I should get output as **sex='M' and department <> 'operation' and department <> 'sales'**

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Is that a YAML file?

Comment: No, it's a text file with .params extension

Comment: It sure looks like [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) with some broken indentation... file extensions don't matter, file content and format do.

Comment: ok. how i can read value from a file based on input in shell script and get the expected output. can you help me on this.

Comment: Since YAML is a structured data format, I'd write something that uses an actual YAML parser to extract the needed data, and then call that from a shell script.

Comment: thank you. but i need this code in shell script (ksh).

Comment: you can read as text file for shell script (ksh)

Comment: I am not using yaml file, its a normal text.

Comment: I don't think you understand *what* YAML is. And good luck doing what you want without a helper program that can understand the format.

Comment: yes, i dont know about YAML.

Comment: my requirement is to use only shell script(ksh) to read value from a text file

Comment: We don't use perl also, only shell script (ksh)

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming you fix the indentation in that example so it's valid YAML, the following perl script produces what you want:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use YAML::XS qw/LoadFile/;

my ($file, $mapping, $table) = @ARGV;

my $yaml = LoadFile $file;

die "No such mapping: $mapping\n" unless exists $yaml->{$mapping};

my %ops = ('==' => '=', 'notin' => '<>');

my $first = 1;
for my $elem (@{$yaml->{$mapping}}) {
    if ($elem->{'table'} eq $table) {
        my $col = $elem->{'column'};
        my $value = $elem->{'value'};
        my $op = $elem->{'operation'};
        $op = $ops{$op} // $op;
        print ' and ' unless $first;
        $first = 0;
        if (ref $value eq 'ARRAY') {
            print join(" and ", map { "$col $op '$_'" } @$value);
        } else {
            print "$col $op '$value'";
        }
    }
}
print "\n";
```

Example:

```
$ perl boringname.pl example.yaml filters employee
sex = 'M' and department <> 'operation' and department <> 'sales'
```

Requires the [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS) module, installable through your favorite CPAN client or your OS package manager (Ubuntu calls the package `libyaml-libyaml-perl`. Not sure about others.).

Comment: I need this block or code of shell script (ksh). can anyone help me on this